# Why can't I see some env vars in GoLand while I can see them from terminal?

Tags: go, terminal, environment-variables

I have the following go program in MacOS:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    name := "NO_PROXY"
    fmt.Printf("value of the env. var. \"%s\" is \"%s\".\n", name, os.Getenv(name))
}
```

If I run it in the IDE (either Run or Debug), it shows the variable is empty:

```
value of the env. var. "NO_PROXY" is "".
```

By contrast, if I run the same script from terminal via `go run main.go` then it shows

```
value of the env. var. "NO_PROXY" is "*.googleapis.com".
```

Why are they different?

Comment: Obviously because the environment variable was not defined in the process which started your IDE, but was defined in shell executed by our terminal. You didn't show how you defined it in these two cases.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the env. var. `NO_PROXY` you can see in terminal is coming from the `.bash_profile`:

```
export NO_PROXY="*.googleapis.com"
```

If a program is executed from terminal, it can see this value.

However, if GoLand is started from the Dock, the `.bash_profile` is not executed, therefore, the variable is not set.

Some solutions:

1. Instead of the Dock, launch Goland from the terminal: `/Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/MacOS/goland`. This way, it will see all the variables the `.bash_profile` specified.
2. Add the environment variable(s) to the Run configuration in GoLand: `Run` → `Edit configurations` → `Environment` → `NO_PROXY=*.googleapis.com;no_proxy=*.googleapis.com`. This way, only the manually added variables will be available for the code.

Note: you can create a permanent command line launcher via `Tools` → `Create Command-line Launcher` if you want to have an easier access.